# Account Generation in Shell Script

Tags: shell, csv

First off, this is my first post on this site but I use it almost regularly. Anyways here it goes.

I'm creating a shell script within linux to generate user accounts with specific usernames and passwords.

The format goes like this for the users: <1stnameinitial>. For the passwords: . These come from a csv file that I have. I have no problem reading the file and making users/pass but I'm stuck on reading the text from the file then translating it into the above specifics. e.g. John Smith 19/02/75 = jsmith js750219

I've looked everywhere and found nothing that will help me. Please help!

Comment: Hello. Usually for getting faster answer, formulate your question as: 1.) "have this input" (provide example) 2.) want the next output (example). 3.) have this constraints (describe), 4.) tried this-and-this (provide some example code what your already tried). 5.) ... :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I really hope these are temporary passwords, they are very insecure :-)

Given an input file of:

```
Kyle Smith 75/02/19
Mary Jones 75/03/20
user 3385643 75/04/21
```

Bash could read the lines of the file like:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=" "
cat file | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | while read first_name last_name dob; do
  echo "dob = $dob"

  # Change field seperator to "/".
  IFS="/"

  # Split the values of dob into an array $dob_data using
  # the new field seperator.
  declare -a dob_data
  dob_data=($dob)
  year=${dob_data[0]}
  month=${dob_data[1]}
  day=${dob_data[2]}

  # Get the first digit of the first_name and last_name.
  first_initial=${first_name:0:1}
  first_initial_lname=${last_name:0:1}

  echo "username = ${first_initial}${last_name}"
  echo "password = ${first_initial}${first_initial_lname}${year}${month}${day}"

  # Restore the field seperator.
  IFS=" "
done
```

Produces:

```
dob = 75/02/19
username = ksmith
password = ks750219
dob = 75/03/20
username = mjones
password = mj750320
dob = 75/04/21
username = u3385643
password = u3750421
```

That said, this would be much more readable if you used a scripting language like Python or Ruby.

Comment: Your code seems to work but my outputs are weird, I'm getting nothing for dob, and first initial and first number of dob for both username and pass. Could this be due to the formatting of my csv file?

Comment: Actually this seems more like a problems with the IFS not working as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about the `sed` and `tr` - something like:

```
sed 's:"\([^ ]\)\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]\)\([^ ]*\)";"\([0-9]*\)/\([0-9]*\)/\([0-9]*\)":\1\3\4/\1\3\7\6\5:' < file.csv | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

in an common csv file text is enclosed in `" "` - for example from

```
"Jim Smith";"19/02/75"
"John Doe";"10/09/65"
"user 321";"1/1/1"
```

produces

```
jsmith/js750219
jdoe/jd650910
u321/u3111
```